# Run a node.js "Script" on aws ec2 with no front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have built a node.js "script" which is basically a single javascript (.js) file which communicates with a smart contract in ethereum blockchain. This needs to be running forever. The problem is, it has no front-end, no server-client architecture so no request / response mechanism needs to be implemented when uploading to aws ec2 instance. This is more like a daemon script which should run in background forever, talking to ethereum blockchain and changing some state variables. So my questions are:

1. Should i keep no front end, and if so, what will happen when i access the public dns?
2. if possible, the only front end I could have is the console logs of the node.js script. Is it possible to configure the front-end (public dns) of ec2 such that the console logs are visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to set up a front-end that only shows the logs, but it sounds like what you're building is more of a service, which wouldn't normally have its own UI. When you hit your instance at its host name (over DNS, for example if you have example.com pointing to your instance) you might not see anything, unless you add an endpoint to return some data. I'd recommend checking out some basic Node API and web server examples, as well as examples in some of the most popular web frameworks (Express, Koa, and Hapi) to see how that would work. But there's nothing wrong with just having a long-running process on an instance that doesn't respond to the outside world.

Comment: but that is exactly what my requirement is, a long running process that doesnt respond to outside world, since the only task it does is communicate with ethereum blockchain and change some state variables there. So web server examples 
 (Express, Koa, Hapi) wont help me. Am i correct in assuming that ? Any ideas on how to manage and run a "service" in ec2 instance?

Comment: If you need to run a Node app that doesn't do any HTTP, yeah, a web server framework isn't the right answer, I think I misunderstood. There's nothing preventing you from just running a Node process, though. `forever` and `pm2` are popular packages for managing long-running processes (including, but definitely not limited to, web servers). If you don't have anything serving on a port, nothing will happen when you hit it over public DNS, but you could bring in Express or similar to serve up logs.

Comment: Good answer. I've heard pm2 itself can also serve up logs?

Comment: I know PM2 has some built-in log management, but I'm not sure about if it can serve up logs, sorry. There might be something in their docs about that though.